# Material shading options in 3d viewport limited for Curve objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, bezier-curves

Render Engine set to Cycles.

For Meshes their diffuse colour is shown in 3d viewport when the Viewport Shading mode is set to Material. Curves do not do this, is there any way to turn this on for Curve objects too? For example below, the silver-grey tubes are Curves and I'd expect them to show the diffuse of the materials assigned to them (black, orange, and blue).

Viewport Shading: Materials
[image]

Renders like this, this is OK, and so is live Viewport rendering:
[image]

The problem is Curves aren't showing their colour, instead a default grey. It doesn't matter which cycles shader-type is used.
[image]

Comment: difficult to understand what you're asking. did you want to see in your viewport, what you are seeing in your render?

Comment: Works for me with cycles and BI, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WsrVM.png, maybe you overwrite the color with a viewport color?

Comment: Same thing, also for Viewport Material Shading: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IpHmi.png

Comment: Whenever using nodes, viewport color is independent from Diffuse Color, to preview your color in the _Material Preview_, copy the value in the _Viewport Color_ slot as shown above

Comment: Thanks poor I get it now, i had never seen that Settings panel, i'm just a nodes guy :)

Comment: Glad I could help, maybe we can script a node to overwrite the color value... btw: really nice icons!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This appears to be fixed in latest builds. no reason to keep the question around

Comment: @zeffii Hm.. It could still be useful, this is actually a pretty good question imo.. But if you really want it gone, then thats fine too.

Comment: OK. leave it. maybe someone with a broken build will stumble into it. I'll track views. if it's static for a long time I'll request deletion again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT

This appears to be fixed in recent builds,

### original

I use Nodes for materials exclusively, and wasn't aware there was an independent Settings panel for the Viewport shading color.

1 and 2 are independent, and unlike Objects which are Meshes, the colour isn't automatic.

[image]

Here the spheres are Mesh based Objects.

[image]

here the blend

[image]

Comment: Since when has the color been automatic for mesh objects?

Comment: Not in 2.74.. Do you perhaps have some addon doing that?

Comment: Hrm.. BI will do this, but cycles never has for me..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23977/discussion-between-gandalf3-and-zeffii).